# How to send JSON data from node js script to HTML file on a different server

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

Okay so I get that the code below is how you send an object to an HTML file using express. But the nodejs code is on a different host than the HTML file. So how do I send the JSON data to that HTML file that's on a different host?

```
Node JS file code:
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});


And HTML file code:

$.ajax({
  url: '/test',
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me clarify a few things.

> the code below is how you send an object to an HTML file

That is not correct.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});
```

What is happing here?  Something sends a `request` to the `/test` endpoint.  It could be a browser, or it could be another server. It could even be an iPhone, or anything with the ability to make a HTTP request.

The `response` is a JSON object:

`{ message: 'Hello World' }`

That means what you already have is enough for another server to `GET` your `message` object @ `/test`.

It's important to know that the response from `/test` is not HTML. It is JSON, which browsers have no trouble displaying.  If you view the page source, you'll see what I mean.

Any server could send a `HTTP` `GET` `request` to `http://example.com/test` and it would receive the `message` JSON as a response **as long as** your server does not restrict the request (i.e. only allow your domain `example.com` to request to `/test`).

**Cross Origin Client Site Requests**

If you want to send an AJAX request to a different domain (`cross origin`), you will need to make sure that the server (express) explicitly allows the client's origin.

**Client:**

```
// From http://test.com
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/test',
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**Server:**

```
// http://example.com
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://test.com');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});
```

Browsers, by default, won't allow you to send an AJAX request to another domain (origin), unless that origin's response includes an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and that header allows the browser's origin. If no such header is present, the request will be blocked by default and you'll see the following error in the console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 2):

you need to enable CORS in expreess app by using middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

this prevents the browser to throw error while making cross domain ajax request

[how to enable cors in express](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)